# label of non-classified examples in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification

What happens if a positive example in neither classified as positive nor negative? Will you treat such an example as False Negative (FN)?

I am using a tool (machine learning) that predicts an example (which is A) as either "A" or "B". However, this tool returns no class for the example. Should you classify the example as FN? I am using supervised classification.

Comment: Can you refrase your question? I couldn't understand

Comment: Please edit to add the clarifying information into the question itself.

Comment: How is it that the tool doesn't return a class? Is it unsure? Has it not seen the pattern? Is it a 3 class classifier?

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the tool. What tool is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A binary classifier has only two possible outputs: `TRUE` and `FALSE`, if your classifier has a third option of `DONT_KNOW`, you have a multi-class classifier.

You might want to have a look at this question regarding multi-classifier:
[Evaluating accuracy of a multi classifier](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/200770/evaluating-accuracy-of-a-multi-classifier)

I would suggest using a measure of belief (a.k.a posterior distribution), that would measure for each specimen $P(y=T)$.

The accuracy can then be measured using [logloss](https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/LogarithmicLoss) for example

Comment: Thanks Goren. Am using a tool that predicts an example as either "A" or "B". However this tool returns an error, with no classification? Should you then classify this example it as False Negative?

Comment: First, you should figure out why the tools throws an error. But talking statistics, I would remove the items that cause the error, and talking into account you might be introducing a bias into the sample.